# running bitcoind for the first time - can't interact. keep getting command not found

Tags: bitcoind

running `ps` yields:

```
31793 pts/0     11:04:46 bitcoind
```

but commands like `bitcoind getblocktemplate`

yields:

```
bash: bitcoind: command not found...
```

I've attempted to add the `src` folder to my global path through the following command:

```
echo " export PATH=$PATH:/home/jpc/Code/WorkingCopies/bitcoin/src" >> ~/.profile
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It sounds like this is more about basic Unix usage than anything specific to bitcoin.  I would change into the directory where `bitcoin-cli` is located and run `./bitcoin-cli`.  Changing PATH like you did is probably not really a good idea, but that's a question for http://unix.stackexchange.com instead of here.

Answer (score 3):

`bitcoind` is the server, you can interact with it using the command-line utility `bitcoin-cli`. For example:

`bitcoin-cli getblocktemplate`

[See this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/32048/difference-between-bitcoin-tx-bitcoin-cli-and-bitcoind) for more info.

Comment: using "bitcoin-cli getblocktemplate" still yields "bash: bitcoin-cli: command not found.

Comment: How did you start `bitcoind` ?

Comment: I'm running Fedora. I was following various online guides (most of which were based on Ubuntu). I believe that the command that got it going after compiling was: "bitcoind -daemon" but later in my history I also see "src/bitcoind &"

Answer (score 0):

I think you should recompile from source.  Visit the bitcoin github repository for Fedora dependencies, you'll find them in doc/build-unix.  Scroll down to Fedora.  Decide whether you want bitcoin-qt or just the command line bitcoin-cli, and whether you really need wallet functionality.

Beware you will need a specific version of Berkeley DB for wallet compatibility.  You can use the latest Berkeley DB though if you don't need or want that compatibility.

Download the source package from https://bitcoincore.org/en/download/. Go into your new src folder, then run

```
./autogen.sh
./configure --without-gui    # see doc/build-unix.md, also for deps
make check

sudo make install    # goes into /usr/local/bin, /usr/local/lib, by default
```

This will likely resolve any issues you have now. You can take the lib paths out of /etc/ld.so.conf and undo changes to your path in ~/.profile.

HTH, let us know how it goes :)

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the detailed response. I am trying to put src/.libs path which is "/home/jpc/Code/WorkingCopies/bitcoin/src/.libs" in /etc/ld.so.conf using emacs (file was read only) and also the command: "echo "/home/jpc/Code/WorkingCopies/bitcoin/src/.libs" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/local.conf (get "bash: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/local.conf: permission denied" I realize this is probably linux 101 type stuff. Trying to get up to speed...

Comment: You're welcome.  It should be readable and writable by root only, and readable by anyone.  Depends on the distribution.  So you would need root privileges, or sudo vim or e.g. `sudo nano /etc/ld.so.conf` and add your `/home/jpc/Code/WorkingCopies/bitcoin/src/.libs` to it.  Save and exit.  Run `sudo ldconfig`.  Now assuming your binaries are on your PATH, give it another shot and let us know?  It's a bit of a shot in the dark, but it's worth a go.  Good luck!

Comment: That worked, /etc/ld.so.conf now reads: include ld.so.conf.d/*.conf (newline) /home/jpc/Code/WorkingCopies/bitcoin/src/.libs (then ran sudo ldconfig) still getting: bitcoin-cli: command not found...

Comment: Still sounds like a PATH issue.   Are you using /bin/bash?  Try putting `PATH="/home/jpc/Code/WorkingCopies/bitcoin/src:$PATH"` in your `~/.profile` at the end, then run `source .profile`.  Stop any bitcoind you might have running, and try running `bitcoind -daemon`.  Then `bitcoin-cli getblockchaininfo` and we'll see...  Are you sure that's the absolute path to where bitcoind and bitcoin-cli binaries are?  Good luck again!

Answer (score 0):

> **commands like `bitcoind getblocktemplate`**

See [chytrik's answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/80972/13866) - you should use the command-line client `bitcoin-cli` not the server `bitcoind`.

> **I've attempted to add the src folder to my global path**

That is generally the wrong thing to do.

- a `src` directory should contain source code. It isn't appropriate to have that on your `$PATH`.
- start by using the full absolute path, e.g. `/home/jpc/Code/WorkingCopies/bitcoin/src/bitcoin-cli getblocktemplate` - if that works see below
- binaries should be installed to somewhere like `/usr/local/bin` (or your distro's equivalent - see Linux Standard Base). Usually this is done using `sudo make install` but check instructions for bitcoin. That folder will already be on your `$PATH`.
- Unless there's a lot of other binaries in a new folder, it is probably better to add an `alias` rather than make the shell search through a large folder for every command you type.

Comment: Using the full absolute path might have provided a clue. When I do that with 'getblocktemplate' or 'getblockchaininfo' Fedora my prompt doesn't come back. Have to use ctrl c to exit. I'm happy to start with a fresh install if necessary or keep trouble shooting? Maybe that clue helps? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to trouble shoot my original binary build, but I used the suggestion James Young made: Reinstall from the bitcoincore.org website tar image. I used the linux build instructions at:

https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#other-linux-distributions

I just needed to update the release version in the commands.

Thank you for all the suggestions. I learned a few good things.

Comment: Note: if you download binary files instead of compiling yourself, be sure to check the developer signatures on the .tar files.